# Put u in front of text python

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I try to replace non-ascii characters with ascii ones.

It works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode

in_text = u"protÃ©gÃ©"

out = unidecode(in_text)

print out
```

result: protA(c)gA(c)

In this case I have to copy text manually.

The problem is in 'u' in front of text.

I'd like to read automatically. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode

with open("C:\Users\B\Desktop\\0.txt", "r") as f:
    in_text = f.read()
    
char_text = u(in_text)

out = unidecode(char_text)
```

python 2.7
https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for python2 only:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import io

with io.open("C:\Users\B\Desktop\\0.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        char_text = u"{}".format(line)
        out = unidecode(char_text)
    print(out)
```

Comment: shows error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Big Daddy/PycharmProjects/untitled/remove non ascii.py", line 7, in <module>
    char_text = u"{}".format(line)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I added encoding = "utf-8" try using my code above again after the edit I made on it.

Comment: different error: line 3, in <module>
    with open("C:\Users\Big Daddy\Desktop\\0.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python      2.7

Comment: Oh encoding = "utf-8" doesnt work with python2, I have updated my code again to work with python2 try it out. (Dont forget to pip install io)